# Infinite loop issue, comparing arrays in java

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a really small program in Java that takes a string as input and uses a function that generates a pseudo random chatacter and compares them to each element of the string, if they're the same the character gets  written to a result array at the same index that it was in the string code is below,

```
public static char randomChar(){

    int diceroll = dice.nextInt(25);    

    return alphabet.charAt(diceroll);

}

public static int itterator(String input){
    char inputchar;
    //convert input string to array
    char[] stringarray = input.toCharArray();

    while(stringarray != result)

        count++;    

    //itterate each character
        for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++)
        {
            inputchar = input.charAt(i);
            if( randomChar() == inputchar )
            {
                result[i] = inputchar;
            }
        }


    return count;
    }
```

The program never terminates however, is this because I have created an infinite loop or is there another reason? Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: I think your infinite loop is here: `while(stringarray != result)

        count++;`

Comment: You should run this in a debugger -- my bet is the problem would very quickly present itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `{}` around your `while` statement, but that's not the only issue you're going to have.

I'm assuming that `result` is a char array too, but I can't see where you've declared it in your code. If it is a char array, then you cannot compare it using `stringarray != result` as it will always be false, causing another infinite loop.

You need to use `Arrays.equals(array1, array2);` in order to do a comparison between arrays.

Change your while statement to:

```
while(!Arrays.equals(stringarray, result)) {
  //code here
}
```

And you will avoid another infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice that silly mistake with the braces and yeah I realised that the way the while loop is comparing the arrays is probably causing the problem (I seem to remember hearing that java compares the memory that the arrays are occupying rather than the contents or something)

Answer (score 1):

This is the guy !

```
while(stringarray != result)

        count++;
```

I guess you missed `{........}` for your `while()`

Answer (score 1):

Here lies your infinite loop :

```
while(stringarray != result)

    count++;
```

Since without braces only the first next line is suppose to be the part of the loop, so in this while loop of your nothing is happening except for incrementing count value.

Do the needful will it. That's it

Regards

Comment: The braces aren't the only problem there. The OP is also testing reference equality, when the intent is probably logical equality (something like `Arrays.equals`). Otherwise, unless you set one reference to equal the other at some point in the loop (which isn't happening here), this will still spin forever.

Comment: @yshavit : That's what i just said, that this loop only incrementing values nothing else, so I cann't assume from myself, what the seeker is intended to do in that while loop, so i said, "Do the needful with it. That's it . "   Regards

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing curly braces after the while statement to enclose the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `while` loop with curly braces and and use the equals method as follows.

```
while(!Arrays.equals(stringarray, result))
{
   //...
}
```

The `Arrays.equals()` method defines as follows.

```
public static boolean equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)
```

Returns `true` if the two specified arrays of Objects are **equal** to one another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. Two objects `e1` and `e2` are considered equal `if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`. In other words, the two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are `null`.